# ¿Como hago que si está logueado no se muestre de nuevo "iniciar sesión" o si no esta logueado no aparezca "Cerrar sesión"?

Tags: php, session

Tengo este error en php, supuestamente esto hace que si está logueado muestre el if, que es para salir, y si no muestre el else, que es para entrar o registrarse, 
pero siempre muestra el if, como si se cumpliera:

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) && $_SESSION['usuario'] != "") { 

echo '<a href="/login/register.php" class="btn btn-tubillar btn-sm boton-login-crear hidden-xs" role="button">Crea tu cuenta</a>
      <a href="/login/index.php" role="button">Ingresar</a>'; 

}else{ 

echo '<a href="/login/cerrar.php" class="btn btn-tubillar btn-sm boton-login-crear hidden-xs" role="button">Salir</a>'; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El código es correcto pero parece que la intención está al revés, igual revisa tus variables si tienes dudas con ellas; `$_SESSION['usuario']`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) && $_SESSION['usuario'] != "") { //si existe la variable 'usuario' y no es igual a "" (suponemos que hay sesión) entonces...
  var_dump($_SESSION);
  echo '<a href="/login/cerrar.php" class="btn btn-tubillar btn-sm boton-login-crear hidden-xs" role="button">Salir</a>';     

}else{ //si no hay variable usuario (suponemos que no hay sesión) entonces...
  var_dump(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : 'No se ha iniciado la sesión, intenta usar session_start(); primero');
  echo '<a href="/login/register.php" class="btn btn-tubillar btn-sm boton-login-crear hidden-xs" role="button">Crea tu cuenta</a>'
      .' <a href="/login/index.php" role="button">Ingresar</a>'; 
}
```

Comment: Me sale `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in `

Comment: Es porque no existe la variable $_SESSION todavía. ¿Estás seguro de que iniciaste la sesión en PHP con `session_start()` ? Edité mi respuesta para que envíe ese mensaje.

Comment: Todo el login lo tengo en una carpeta llamada /login/ adentro de la carpeta donde tengo el index.php, que es el que tiene los botones entrar y registrarse